# Windows is missing in GRUB!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have Ubuntu 16.10 with Windows 7. I installed Ubuntu ( first ) then I created a partition for Windows, then installed it on the partition so that deleted GRUB. So I restored GRUB , but now Windows 7 is not appearing in GRUB.

Any solutions on how to add Windows 7 to GRUB?

Comment: Have you run *sudo update-grub* yet? That's all you need, probably.

Comment: @CelticWarrior - LOL! Your comment appeared 1/4 second after I submitted my answer.

Comment: @AndroidDev How did you measured it with such precision?

Comment: @CelticWarrior - Well I can't say that it was that amount of time exactly, but it wasn't there when I hit submit, and it was after I hit submit...

Comment: LOL @ two of the world's best Ubuntu Ninja's bumping keyboards on same thread.. I would have posted answer `sudo update-grub` as a one liner and beaten both of you but I was 5 minutes late to the play-offs :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Boot into Ubuntu
2. Open a terminal
3. Run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: THANKS, but sorry for the extremely late reply!

Answer (score 5):

Try `boot-repair` on Ubuntu. It should fix many of the common errors and/or issues related to `GRUB`.

Comment: There's absolutely no need for that tool. This situation is quite simple to solve. Please chack the comments and other answers.

Comment: Ok I posted it because there wasn't a reply if it worked for an hour

Comment: There were comments and a correct and accepted answer one hour before you posted ;-)

Comment: @darjan2002 that doesn't work on BIOS systems only UEFI systems and I am BIOS

Comment: @NaiemdaLegend actually, that gpt thing is a dropdown. click it and select the first option (MBR for BIOS)